# Using branch name dynamically from GitHub README file

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-resource-manager

I have a GitHub repo with Azure RM templates ready for deployments.
I included in my repo's README file links that refer to a certain template in my repo and opens the Azure Portal with the template loaded and ready for deployment. the branch name master is hardcoded:
href=https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Forg%2Frepo-name%2F**master**%2Fazure%2Ftemplate.json

I want to make the branch name dynamic, which means if I click the README link from branch 'develop' for instance, the link will be:
href=https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Forg%2Frepo-name%2F**develop**%2Fazure%2Ftemplate.json

I don't want to use GitHub Actions for this, I am looking for some kind of environment variable that can be reached from anywhere in the repo, describing the current branch.

Comment: Either you are asking for existing software, which is separately off-topic (recommendation questions); or you are asking much too vaguely about how to solve this yourself. Please review [what to avoid on Stack Overflow.](/help/dont-ask)